# Unable to select just certain columns from table with Entity Framework - get anonymous type error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5.1, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to select only certain columns from a table using EF 6.1. However, it won't let me pull back just the columns I want. I have to pull back every column from the table which has 14,000 rows so the query takes ~30 seconds. The column that kills the query is a NVARCHAR in the table. But with EF it's all or nothing. I am using IEnumerable also. Perhaps I should be using IQueryable?>

Using this query I get an anonymous type error:

```
 Using db As Ctx = New Ctx
     Dim postcount = db.be_Posts.Count
     posts = db.be_Posts.Select(Function(S) New With {S.DateCreated, S.Description, S.PostRowID, S.Title}).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.DateCreated)
     Return posts.ToList
 End Using
```

Error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`4[System.DateTime,System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
```

This works but is getting all the records and the columns I don't need:

```
Using db As Ctx = New Ctx
            Dim postcount = db.be_Posts.Count
            posts = db.be_Posts.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.DateCreated).ToList

            Return posts
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Create PostSummaryDto class:

   public class PostSummaryDto 
   {
       public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
       ...rest of fields...
   }
2. Use PostSummaryDto class in query:

   New PostSummaryDto { DateCreated = S.DateCreated, ...}
3. Define return type of function as `IEnumerable<PostSummaryDto>`.

I am not a fan of Visual Basic, so I am not sure if returning anonymous types is allowed, but I believe it is good custom to define return types clearly.

Comment: Thanks. That helped speed up the query. Now I just have to figure how to use Troy Goode's ToPagedList extension with a repository or implement my own paging solution.